# Can't click a "next" button using xpath, .select nor Selenium using Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click the "next" button on the bottom of this page: https://www.domcop.com/domains/great-expired-domains/

I've tried with a css selector using .select, with xpath and with Selenium and nothing worked.

I think the button is generating a JQuery code to list the domains on the same page which would explain why python can't click it with xpath and .select.

However, I couldn't figure out how to click it with Selenium...

Here's my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.domcop.com/domains/great-expired-domains/")
assert "Python" in driver.title
link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next').get_attribute('a')
```

It returns a 'NoneType' object...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to find both buttons.
2. Scroll down to the bottom.
3. Click the 2nd button.

See code below:

```
driver.get('https://www.domcop.com/domains/great-expired-domains/')    
aElements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.next > a')
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);') 
aElements[1].click()
```

Answer (score 3):

Unlike common XML/HTML parser, selenium simulates browser behaviour, so it shouldn't have problem with elements generated by JQuery as you seem concrerned about. The problem with your selector was, that `a` is *not attribute* of element with class `next`, it is *child* of `next` instead. Therefore you can use CSS selector for child `>` here :

```
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.next > a')
link.click()
```

Comment: cool upvoted .. I have a query is . represent a class? .. how you create this css selector.. a lil bit explanation or any article on same or tutorial will help.. Thanks :)

Comment: @ShubhamJain Yes, `.` is notation for class selector in CSS, similar to `@` for attribute in XPath. I believe all basics/introduction to CSS cover this, for example : [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) by MDN, or [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) from http://code.tutsplus.com

Answer (score 0):

[image]find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="domcop-table_wrapper"]/div[position()>1]/div[position()>1]/div/ul/li[6]/a/i[@class="icon-double-angle-right"]')

**This Xpath will ALWAYS work.** You can scroll down afterwards and click

I just did not scroll down. thats all.

Check this Xpath

```
(:xpath, '//*[@id="domcop-table_wrapper"]/div[not(contains(text(),
"Display")) and not(contains(text(),"records"))]/descendant::li[@class="next"]/a/i[@class="icon-double-angle-right"]')
```

Comment: This is the most Definitive a = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="domcop-table_wrapper"]/div[not(contains(text(), "Display")) and not(contains(text(), "records"))]/div[not(contains(text(), " to ")) and not(contains(text(), " of "))]/div/ul/li[@class="next"]/a/i[@class="icon-double-angle-right"]') 
OR
(:xpath, '//*[@id="domcop-table_wrapper"]/div[position()>1]/div[not(contains(text(), " to ")) and not(contains(text(), " of "))]/div/ul/li[@class="next"]/a/i[@class="icon-double-angle-right"]')

Comment: ElementNeeded = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="domcop-table_wrapper"]/div[not(contains(text(), "Display")) and not(contains(text(), "records"))]/descendant::li[@class="next"]/a/i[@class="icon-double-angle-right"]');  
ElementNeeded.location_once_scrolled_into_view;
ElementNeededa.click